# SQL query count and distinct year

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Hi I am trying to do the following query. Basically im trying to count all musicians that exist that are born in 1990.

```
SELECT COUNT(MusicianID), 
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN year(DateOfBirth)=1990)
FROM Musician
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 SELECT COUNT(MusicianID) As allmusicians
 FROM Musician
 WHERE year(DateOfBirth) = 1990
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(MusicianID)
FROM Musician
WHERE YEAR(DateOfBirth)=1990
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select count(musicianid)
from musician
Where year(date of birth) = 1990
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
SELECT COUNT(MusicianID)
FROM Musician
WHERE YEAR(DateOfBirth)=1990
```